# Need Help in applying constraints to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm adding subviews programmatically.
**Requirement :** when extra views are added the scroll should be enabled.
The constraints that I applied :
[image]

To remove extra spaces at the top I wrote `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`
also give content size as `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height*2)`

But the when the view is loaded scroll is completely disabled.

Please help me

Comment: what is your contentSize when you print it out?

Comment: when I printed it, it has showed as (375.0,1334.0)

Comment: Have you checked Bounces and Bounces Vertically in your IB? And also Scrolling Enabled

Comment: set content size in viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: @jo3birdtalk , these are checked. and they are just bouncing but not scrolling up.

Comment: Thanks @karthikeyan , setting in viewWillLayoutSubviews method is working. Please make an answer.

Comment: @RamcharanReddy as you said, i have updated as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you using auto layout, you have to set **content size** at **viewcontroller** method, you have to **override** following method.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews;
```

**swift**

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set contentview height, based on (origin.y + height) of subview at bottom in scroll contentview.

Comment: I appreciate the idea.where do i set it?

Comment: After adding subviews programatically in contentview.

Comment: When I'm using autolayouts, is it good practice to assign height to explicitly. 
And it is also not working.

Comment: As you're adding subviews programmatically, you have to change contentview height according height of all subviews in it. So you can assign height programmatically with autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that you need to do, check that you have this enabled.

1. Bounces
2. Bounces Vertically
3. Scrolling Enabled

If enabling those still doesn't help with the scrolling, add a Height constraint of your `ContentView`. You have to connect this constraint as an `IBOutlet` to your View Controller.

I believe your data is fetched from server, as such you have an ambiguous content height. So at where you print the `contentSize` of value `(375.0,1334.0)` in your question, add this line of code and you should be able to scroll thereafter.

```
YourHeightConstraint.constant = self.scrollView.contentSize.height
```