# scrollview scrolling on iphone x simulator but not other devices

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have the following code which sets up the layout of a signup view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.mainWhite()

        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)

        setupView()
        addKeyboardObservers()
        assignFirstResponders()
    }

    func setupView() {

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        scrollView.addSubview(logoView)
        logoView.anchor(top: scrollView.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 110, height: 110)
        logoView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [emailTextField, passwordTextField, confirmPasswordTextField, firstNameTextField, lastNameTextField, phoneNumberTextField , signupButton])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 4
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually

        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.anchor(top: logoView.bottomAnchor, left: scrollView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: scrollView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 60, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 60, width: 0, height: 350)
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        scrollView.addSubview(alreadyHaveAccountButton)
        alreadyHaveAccountButton.anchor(top: stackView.bottomAnchor, left: scrollView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: scrollView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 12, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 50)

        scrollView.addSubview(footerView)
        footerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        footerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        footerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        footerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
        footerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        footerView.addSubview(termsAndPrivacyButton)
        termsAndPrivacyButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        termsAndPrivacyButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        termsAndPrivacyButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func assignFirstResponders() {
        emailTextField.delegate = self
        passwordTextField.delegate = self
        confirmPasswordTextField.delegate = self
        firstNameTextField.delegate = self
        lastNameTextField.delegate = self
        phoneNumberTextField.delegate = self
    }
```

I need the view to scroll when the keyboard overlaps an input view. And I've seen plenty of solutions for that here that address that.

```
extension SignupViewController {

    func addKeyboardObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SignupViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SignupViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

        var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
        contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height + 15
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInset

        print("content inset: \(scrollView.contentInset) \nKeyboard frame \(keyboardFrame)")
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
}
```

The issue I'm encountering now is that the scrolling functionality is **ONLY** working on the iPhone X simulator. When I test on my actual iPhone 6s device, the scrolling does not work. I've tried all all simualtor devices and the scrollign only works on the iphone X simulator which is extremely strange. Has anyone encountered something like this?

Comment: set your contentSize in Viewdidlayoutsubviews and check once

Comment: @karthikeyan wow. This did it. Thank you so much.

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951644/need-help-in-applying-constraints-to-uiscrollview/41958484#41958484